# Using an sql-function when reading and writing with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following problem.

I have a special column in my tables (a blob). In order to read and write to that column, I need to call an SQL function on its value - to convert to a string when I read, and to convert from a string to this blob when I write.

The read part is easy - I can use a formula to run the sql function against the column. But formulas are read only. Using IUserType also did not seem to assist - I can get the blob and write my own code to convert it to my own type, but I don't want to do that - I already have a database function that does this work for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify sql to insert and update, see the [reference documentation, "Custom SQL for create, update and delete"](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-cud). Here is [an example from Ayende](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/18/UsingNHibernateWithStoredProcedures.aspx) which uses stored procedures (which is not the same, just to see how it works).

Or you could write a database trigger which does this transformation.

Comment: I know I could do this, but it would make everything much more cumbersome. This field is in a very large part of my tables, and I don't want to specify custom sql for each entity in my mapping. I was hoping to find a generic way to handle this type of column.